# PIC18F SPI SDI line affecting/distorting data from slave device?

Tags: pic, spi, flash

I have a PIC18F14K22 connected to a flash memory chip (Winbond W25Q80BV) via SPI and am having trouble reading the output from the chip. Specifically, the flash data output becomes distorted when I connect its output line to the SDI PIC pin. If I just watch the flash output from a logic analyzer, I can verify the correct output is being produced. My thought is that possibly the SDI line (RB4) is not in High-Z mode, but I explicitly am setting it as an input: 
TRISBbits.RB4 = 1;    // RB4/SDI is an input

Note that I can use this SPI port successfully with another chip (not a memory chip, something else).

I have tried pulling the line high and low to bias in either direction. However, the line DOES change level, just not quickly enough or maybe is not strong enough to produce the correct signal.

Here is a demonstration from the logic analyzer of when the SO signal looks correct (not connected to PIC SDI) and then after I connect it, the incorrect signal: http://imgur.com/Nbhg6FJ,gonA2H5#0

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried connecting it to a different input on the PIC to see what happens? Are they on the same logic supplies?

Comment: @Andyaka, good question. I just tried hooking the MISO to another GPIO (also set to input/highz) and observe the same problem. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Can you look at the MISO line on a scope?

Comment: unless that scope is in digital only meaning it only shows high low levels it doesn't look like there's any line contention or you would see strange transitions or something like a low high level. how are you sure what value is supposed to be there?